# geth subscribe newHeads not working

Tags: go-ethereum, websocket

I run geth with this command

> geth --syncmode "fast" --cache 2048 --datadir /data/ethereum --ws
>   --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsorigins '*' --wsapi 'web3,eth,net,db,personal' --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0

then i subscribe newHeads and recieve `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x30ebfd74dc99548d16b64d23eda6f964"}`.But can not recieve any block head.I try to connect infura `wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws` and recieve new block head.

```py
import websocket
import json
import time
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        ws.send(json.dumps({"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newHeads"]}))
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    # ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws",
    ws=websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://127.0.0.1:8546",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Am I wrong ? My geth version is Geth/v1.9.6-stable-bd059680/linux-amd64/go1.13.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether your Geth node is completely synced

Comment: only full sync support subscribe?

Comment: no, Fast sync will support subscription, what I just meant is to check whether the node synced completely or not?

Comment: oh, i checkecd that the node synced completely. But steel can not recieve response

Comment: try this on your terminal -- > wscat -c "ws://127.0.01:8546"       then > {"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newHeads"]}

Comment: Thank you. I tried this,  but only response `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x3ce062dfc36449fb8b3cdde5ee437e17"}`

Comment: sorry, I checked sync again. The node is not synced completely...